# Fail to load DLLS on IIS v6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have written a web service that calls an external DLL. DLL is added to BIN directory.
when I debug program using visual Studio it runs without any problem.
But when I publish it on IIS6 and  external DLL is called an error is returned in message box  and following error is returned by web service. So I can't see the error to solve the problem.
(External DLL returns errors in message box and I have not access to the source of DLL)

- Windows server 2003 64 bit
- IIS v6

How can I see the Error?
what is the cause of problem?

`Error at Configuration. ---> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.`

Answer (score 0):

i believe there are some security issue. And windows trying to show error dialog. When you debug the application is running under your user profile. Most probably that has different access right than the application pool user right. 
Add try catch around your call to the dll and log the details either in event log or in logfile to get details. 
You may also try to add the dll to GAC.

Comment: When I add try catch the same error is in inner exception. I believe error is from DLL.